# Create new array from total by modulo

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
const total = 512;
```

Need to divide by modulo with size of an array

I want result like this,

```
const newArray = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 12];
// const newArray = [sizeofarray, sizeofarray, ...etc].
```

// 5 times 100 and 12

Comment: where do you get the array from? what have you tried? what does not work?

Comment: What is your original array? And what does size mean here for you? In javascript the size of the array is the lenght of that array. Is it?

Comment: I want to call API in chunks by total count with rxjs epic function so I have total count, I need to generate array that will call API in the loop by size.
so I need the above newArray result which is the size of the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz The array is what OP wants to create from the `total`. `512` = 5 times `100` and `12`.

Comment: @ReactNative So basically you have 2 information total and size of the array. And you want to modulo of the same array size in a new array. Right!

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya He has a total and a chunk size. The array size is the floor of `total` divided by the chunk size + maybe 1 for the rest.

Comment: please give the rule for the parts. a single example is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array.from`

```js
const gen = (num, size) => {
  const rem = num % size;
  const length = Math.ceil(num / size);
  return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) =>
    (rem !== 0 && i === length - 1) ? rem : size
  );
};

console.log(gen(512, 100));
console.log(gen(500, 100));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```js
const generator = (total, divider) => {
  let result = Math.round(total/divider);
  let remain = total % divider;
    const tableResult = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < result; i++) {
    tableResult.push(divider);
  }
  tableResult.push(remain);
  return tableResult;
}

console.log(generator(512, 100));
```

Comment: When total = 479 and divider=500 then it's not working

Comment: What type of result do you want the function to return when total is less than the divider

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create an array with the modulo value, later you can push the remain value

```
`const total = 512;

 let count = total/100;
 let newArr = new Array(Math.floor(count)).fill(100)
 if(count%1 != 0){
   newArr.push(total%100)
 }

 console.log(newArr) // output`
```

Comment: @ReactNative Kindly make it as correct ans, if it works for you, so it can help other users too

Comment: When total = 479 and page size 500 then it's not working